# How do I persist an object to a binary file in PHP?

Tags: php, function, oop, serialization, ascii

I know about the [`serialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function in PHP, but that turns the object into an ASCII string, which can then be placed in a file.

What if I was to write it as binary data in a file? How would I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually returns a binary string , not ASCII.

From the [**PHP Manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)..

> Returns a string containing a byte-stream representation of value that
>   can be stored anywhere.
>
> **Note that this is a binary string which may include null bytes, and
>   needs to be stored and handled as such**. For example, serialize()
>   output should generally be stored in a BLOB field in a database,
>   rather than a CHAR or TEXT field.

Comment: then how would I write it as binary data?

Comment: That is a binary data right .. ? So why don't you write it as it is , you could later use `unserialize()` to get them back.

Comment: Yeah that's a binary stream , you just can't expect to see 0's and 1's I guess. Are you worried since the data is being exposed ?

Comment: I was expecting something less legible though (not that it was a security concern or anything) - I just thought binary data was a little more... binary.